# Linq query on related entities

Tags: linq

this may be a very basic question but I haven't used Linq much so do need help. 
I want to retrieve a list of records based on the related record count.

for example:

I have contact entity which has 1:N relationship with a 'Role' entity. I want to select contacts that have

1. No related roles
2. only 1 related role

How do I write this using Linq

```
from contact in context.ContactSet
where <contact.Roles has no records> -- ?? 
select contact;
```

Please help.

Comment: Remember to accept an answer (click on the tick) if you deem it the correct solution to your problem or upvote other helpful answers. Enjoy SO :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check by using `Count() <= 1`

Linq style:

```
from contact in context.ContactSet
where contact.Roles.Count() <= 1
select contact;
```

Method style:

```
context.ContactSet.Where(c => c.Roles.Count() <= 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Description

You can use the `Count()` or `Any()` method

> **Count()** - Returns the number of elements in a sequence.
>
> **Any()** - Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition.

### Sample

#### Count()

**Query Syntax**

```
from contact in context.ContactSet
where contact.Roles.Count() == 0
select contact;
```

**Method Syntax**

```
context.ContactSet.Where(c=> c.Roles.Count() != 0));
```

#### Any()

**Query Syntax**

```
from contact in context.ContactSet
where !contact.Roles.Any()
select contact;
```

**Method Syntax**

```
context.ContactSet.Where(c=> !c.Roles.Any());
```

### There is no difference in performance between method and query syntax both will compiled into the same.

### More Information

- [MSDN - Enumerable.Count Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count.aspx)
- [MSDN - Enumerable.Any Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To select contacts with no roles:

```
from contact in context.ContactSet
where !contact.Roles.Any()
select contact;
```

or simply:

```
context.ContactSet.Where(c=> !c.Roles.Any());
```

To select contacts with n roles assigned:

```
from contact in context.ContactSet
where contact.Roles.Count()==n
select contact;
```

or simply:

```
context.ContactSet.Where(c=> c.Roles.Count()==n));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. Here is my problem with the Roles.Any() function; Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.    My 'Roles' relationship is of type IEnumberable<relatedentity>

Comment: That's not working either. I am working with Microsoft Dynamics CRM early bound entity classes and it looks like I will have to work in a different way. Looks like I have to explicityly use the lazy loading for the related entities.

Answer (score 1):

The following will select all contacts that have exactly 0 or 1 items in the `Roles` collection. Depending on the type of collection and the data access technology the `Count` property may by a method, e.g. `Count()`. (`Count` also has overloads so you can conditionally count items, e.g. `.Count(x => x.SomeProperty && !x.SomeOtherProperty)`

```
from contact in context.ContactSet
where contact.Roles.Count <= 1
select contact;
```

Comment: Correct answer - but how about adding some text?

Comment: @AndreasRehm - description added

Comment: Thank you - will be more descriptive next time :)